# Visual 2017 C# and Unity, Can't refer to Google namespace, Namespace doesn't autofill

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-platform, visual-studio-2017, google-cloud-storage

I am getting the following error when trying to refer to the Google Cloud Platform libraries in my C# project:
"The type or namespace name 'Google' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" .

I've successfully installed the Google cloud API packages using Package Manager, shouldn't I be able to type "using Google.Cloud.Storage.v1" and implement that library's code?

For clarity, I am using Visual Studio to edit a Unity script.

[As shown, the google namespace doesn't autofill](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQMJp.png)

Comment: A couple stupid sounding questions.  Are you sure the package installed successfully?  And are you sure you are installing the package into the correct project?

Comment: My apologies, I haven't been coding in C# for long, and I'm relatively new to coding in general. I'm sure the package installed successfully, though I could be installing it into the incorrect project, for all I know. I'm installing it into all the projects in the solution, in such a way that each library is found in the "Packages" folder within Windows Explorer. However they don't show up in that folder within Unity

Comment: you should check your references, within the solution explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to just make a Windows Forms app which is launched from a unity script, which doesn't reference unity. That program had no issues connecting to Google Cloud.